# Pixelated normals while baking problem

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, texture-baking, baking, normal-map

I'm new to blender and i just started to bake normal.In my case i am trying to bake details from high poly to a low poly obj but it gets pixelated(image below) along the curve.Can u please guide me on a workaround.i have also posted my render settings hope that helps

[image]

[image]

Comment: that seems to be due to the texture (image) resolution (size)

Comment: How do i fix it ? Current img size is 1024x1024 px . Update : i created a new img of 2048x2048 px and rebaked but still  Normals are pixelated

Comment: Hard to be totally sure it is the reason. What you can try is to give more space for this corner. To do that, mark seems around it and scale up this UV map part in your texture. If this still does not work, tell here...

Comment: So you have a high poly model and a low poly model? Which one is the model in your screenshot? Maybe you should upload your model to exchange.giantcowfilms.com/, edit your question and post the link there?

Comment: Hey thank u for feedback. I tried uploading through the site u mentioned but i got server code 0 error ;/ . And yes im baking highpoly(image) to low( which doesnt have extruded lines in it )

Comment: Sorry, wrong link. Try http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/